# Bash Script For Loop *

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

What is the meaning of:

```
for i in *; do echo *; done
```

I am on Unix Terminal (Mac OS X)

```
Darwin localhost 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit redundant. In both places, the `*` will expand to every file in the current directory. So the loop will repeat once for every file, with `i` set to a different file name each time. Then the body will simply output the name of every file, ignoring `i`. So if you have 10 files in the directory, you'll print all 10 file names 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

many special symbol are used under unix shell,for about bash.

* represent all file name under current directory which split by space,you can use echo * for a test.

~ represent you home directory.

! used for history command.

# for the comment.

$ used for recognize variable

% used for jobs

^ used for history command,format as '^string1^string2^' to quick substitution.

& used for background job

* all file name under current directory which split by space.

()  cooperate with $,$(command) equivalent with `command`,$((1 + 2)) calculate mathematic expression like expr command do.

- used for old pwd,you can use 'cd -' back to the directory you switch from.

= use for assignment.

you code

```
for i in *; do echo *; done
```

just a for loop print all file name under current directory.